# 2 people within a distance of each other in a random walk (CHMMC individual #2, 2016)

Tags: contest-math, random-walk

> Alice and Bob find themselves on a coordinate plane at time t = 0 at points A(1, 0), and
>   B(−1, 0). They have no sense of direction, but they want to find each other. They each pick a direction
>   with uniform random probability. Both Alice and Bob travel at speed 1
>   unit
>   / min in their chosen directions. They
>   continue on their straight line paths forever, each hoping to catch sight of the other. They each have a 1-unit
>   radius field of view: they can see something iff its distance to them is at most 1. What is the probability that
>   they will ever see each other?

So basically we have two lines with random slope through A and B. So the equations of the lines can be $A_x(t)=t, A_y(t) = m_1(t-1)$ and $B_x(t)=t, B_y(t) = m_2(t+1).$ And because we have to account for direction, we have to divide by 4 at the end. How to proceed from here?

Edit 1: As the movement speed of the people have to be constant, the parameterization should be $A_x(t)=t m_2/m_1, A_y(t) = m_1(m_2t/m_1-1)=m_2t-m_1$ and $B_x(t)=t, B_y(t) = m_2(t+1).$

Edit 2: I was thinking, instead of parametizing through a line, it would make more sense to parameterize through an angle. Then $A_x(t) = -1 + t\sin \theta_1, A_y(t) = t\cos\theta_1$, $B_x(t) = 1 + t\sin \theta_2, B_y(t) = t\cos\theta_2$.

Comment: Note that they can also pick a direction straight upward or downward, which your parametrisation does not allow, and it also makes it difficult to express them choosing a direction with uniform probability. In addition, your parametrisation will  not have them walk at the same velocity if their slopes are different. You need to express $A_x, A_y, B_x$ and $B_y$ differently to take all of this into account.

Comment: @Arthur I would think that the upward/downward case occurs with probability 0, so they can be ignored.

Comment: Well, technically, yes, that's true. However, the most natural way to account for my other two points will take care of that one as well.

Comment: @Arthur I see! an Angular parameterization would work quite well, right?

Comment: Exactly. Lastly, I would advise you to examine the line $C(t) = A(t) - B(t)$, what its properties are, and how "Alice and Bob are at most one unit distance apart from one another" would be phrased in terms of $C$. That makes the calculations slightly easier.

Comment: @Arthur after some manipulations, I get that the probability is 2 arctan(1/2)/pi. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

With probability ${1\over2}$ they both walk into the same (lower or upper) half plane. Conditioning on this we may assume their orbits to be
$$a(t)=(1-t\cos\alpha,t\sin\alpha),\qquad b(t)=(-1+t\cos\beta,t\sin\beta)$$
with angles $\alpha$, $\beta$  independently and uniformly distributed in $[0,\pi]$. If $\alpha+\beta>\pi$ then they walk apart right from the start. We therefore condition on $\alpha+\beta\leq\pi$, which introduces another factor ${1\over2}$ in the overall probability of seeing each other.

We now compute
$$f(t):=\bigl|a(t)-b(t)\bigr|^2=4-4t(\cos\alpha+\cos\beta)+2t^2(1+\cos(\alpha+\beta)\ .$$
The minimum of this function is assumed at time
$$t_*={\cos\alpha+\cos\beta\over1+\cos(\alpha+\beta)}\ ,$$
which is indeed positive when $\alpha+\beta<\pi$. This means that the distance between the two is initially decreasing, assumes the minimal value
$$m:=\sqrt{f(t_*)}=2\left|\sin{\alpha-\beta\over2}\right|$$
(Mathematica computed this for me),
and then will increase forever. The condition $m\leq1$ amounts to
$$|\alpha-\beta|\leq{\pi\over3}\ .\tag{1}$$
We now  draw the triangle $\{(\alpha,\beta)\>|\>\alpha\geq0,\ \beta\geq0,\  \alpha+\beta\leq\pi\}$ and compute the fraction $\rho$ of its area defined by $(1)$. One obtains
$$\rho={\pi^2/2-2\pi^2/9\over\pi^2/2}={5\over9}\ .$$
The probability $p$ we are looking for is therefore given by
$$p={1\over2}\cdot{1\over2}\cdot{5\over9}={5\over36}\ .$$

Comment: They can meet up without moving into the same half-plane.

Comment: @Arthur: See my edit. Hope it's clear now.